# Ipython Prompt commad

Tags: python, installation, download, ipython, command-prompt

i am completely ignorant with the prompt command, i don't know anything so be crystal clear when explaining step by step, thanks.
I have installed Python 3.10.4, if i digit python in the command prompt it works.
Then i installed pip using python get-pip.py and it told me it was successfully installed.
I went on ipython website and i downloaded the ipython file. At this point i went on the command prompt and i wrote "pip install ipython" and it installed it.
Now if i write "ipython" in the command prompt it says "ipython is not recognized as an internal or external command". If i try to install it again it says everything is already installed.
Help me i don't know what to do.

Comment: You need to add that to PATH

Comment: are you under linux? try running `ipython3` you may also need to add `~/.local/bin` to your `PATH`

Comment: I am under windows

Comment: How do i  add a Path?

Comment: I think i found out the Location of ipython. Can you show me how to add the path in windows prompt commnad? I spent hours trying to find a solution... :(

Comment: Try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee537574(v=office.14)) (disclaimer: I don't use Windows).

Comment: @JohnPi Try this `python -m IPython`

Comment: Yes, it worked. Can you explain what the command -m does?